# Are CakePHP Database Sessions Auto-magically Cleaned?

Tags: session, cakephp-1.3

I am using Cakephp 1.3 and saving sessions in my database.

So far none of the sessions that have been created have been cleared from the 'cake_sessions" table.

I'd like to know if CakePHP core or a process clears session rows from this table or do I need to take care of this. If CakePHP core or a process is auto-magically taking care of this, what are possible reasons why session entries in my table are not being cleared/

Answer (score 2):

I've just been Googling this exact question (glad you asked it).  Had to ask the devs on #CakePHP IRC.

Apparently **the database is cleaned when garbage collection is triggered by PHP**.  By default, this is roughly every 1,000 requests.  You can control the frequency by setting `session.gc_divisor`.

```
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 1000);    // this is the default
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 1);       // this will run GC on every request
                                        // (helpful for debugging)
```

At least this is true for CakePHP 2.x, but I suspect it applies to 1.3 also.

Comment: I had moved away from this topic a while ago, and I have also have moved away from CakePHP so I will not be able validate your answer. Thank you for replying nonetheless. Appreciate it.